# How to remove youtube recomended videos at the end of my video?

Tags: html, video, youtube

I am trying to embed youtube video (my own) on my blog and I don't want to see recommended videos at the end, unfortunately ?rel=0 or &rel=0 doesn't work.

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MY_VIDEO_ID?rel=0" allowfullscreen=""> </iframe>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try not using Youtube, but something else, vimeo or jwplayer? Or may be if you create a youtube channel where you upload multiple copies of this video it will look like it's looping..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this adding end of the embedded link 
?rel=0& showinfo=0

**Example -**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZJDMWVZta3M?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```